# Continued inoperation of PIC microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, power, microchip, mplabx

I have a PIC16F18076 microcontroller that I have been trying to get working and it hasn't been working at all, I cannot get any of the microcontrollers(I have 5) to show any sign of doing anything I program them to do. I connect LEDS and voltmeters to the GPIO's and there is no sign of any significant power output:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmk1F3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

```
#include "mcc_generated_files/system/system.h"

/*
    Main application
*/

int main(void)
{
    SYSTEM_Initialize();

    while(1)
    {
        TL_SetHigh();
        TR_SetHigh();
    }    
}
```

I have extremely simple code I am programming and still despite a report from the pickit that the device has been programmed just fine the microchip continues to have no sign of life any of its GPIO pins. I am out of ideas as to what could be wrong.

Comment: Most PICs require a clock crystal (usually 4MHz) and two "loading capacitors" to do anything, even program.  Some can be programmed to run from an internal clock, like this [PIC16F18076](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/PIC16F18056-76-28-40-Pin-Microcontroller-Data-Sheet-40002325B.pdf).  But these usually default to external clock source - not using the internal clock by default - meaning, you'll need to program them once first, outside of your circuit, using something like the PICKit 4.

Comment: @rdtsc I did that and it is set to an internal clock oscillator

Comment: Did you configure these GPIOs as outputs?

Comment: @Jens Yes I did

Comment: What happens when  you use your PICkit as a debugger (instead of just a programmer) and step through your code?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet mostly because I'm not super sure how, but to me the code seems simple enough so I have only bothered externally debugging

Comment: Immediately crashes and reboot due to the lack of current limiting resistor on the LED ?
Thus is booted but crashes as soon as it tried to power on the LED ?

Comment: Well I have also tested it with a voltmeter instead of an LED and the LED has turned on before with the microcontroller

Comment: Did you switch your GPIO to digital? Maybe they are analog pins. And your LED need a resistor to limit the current.

Comment: I did, and forget the LED I've just been measuring with a voltmeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To any future readers of this post, I was so frustrated that this wouldn't work and spent so many hours trying to figure out what the matter was. The **simple answer was to open the configuration bits, and do everything you can to force high voltage programing and disabling all prompts mentioning an external oscillator in the MCC configuration bits tab.** This instantly solved the problem and in fact the circuit works just fine without pulling MCLEAR high or using any capacitors.